# Wrong value of input number returned

Tags: php

I'm doing this assignment where I have to do website. I created a input number for the quantity of the product with a button all this in a form. When I try to get the quantity by putting in the URL. The problem is I keep getting the wrong quantity. Not the quantity that I had in my input.

```
<?php
foreach ($productList as $product){
?>
<form action="index.php" method="post">
<?php echo "<ul class='row'>"?>
<?php echo "<li>"?>
<?php echo "<img src ='".$product->getImage()."'class=image'>" ?>
<?php echo "<div class='overlay'>"?>
<?php echo '<div class="text">'.$product->__toString()."</div>"?>
<?php echo "</div>"?>
<?php
    echo"<p id ='titleQte'>Quantity </p>";
    echo"<div class='qteProduct'>";
    echo "<input type='number' name='qte' value='1' min = '1'/>";
    echo"</div>";
    echo"<a href=index.php?action=addCartProduct&id=".$product->getId().'&quantity='.((isset($_POST['qte'])) && (isset($_POST['btnAjout'])) ? $_POST['qte']:1).'>'."<button type='button' name='btnAdd' id='add' class='btn btn-success'>Add to Cart</button></a>";
?>
<?php echo "</li>"?>
<?php echo "</ul>"?>

</form>
<?php
}
?>
```

It gives me 1 instead of the actual value of the input.
Some help would be appreciated. 
Thank you.

Comment: Your whole script construction is very strange.

Question. Why are you looping through $productList?

You're essentially just refreshing the page each and every time so I think you have some fundamental construction problems here that you might want to rethink.

Comment: I'm also not seeing any actual submit button.

Comment: I'm doing it in MVC therefore, the product list is from my product class where I made a list with my infos of my product. This list is in my Product Modal which is called in my View that I share with yall

Comment: & I used a button from a bootstrap "<button type='button' name='btnAdd' id='add' class='btn btn-success'>Add to Cart</button>"

Comment: Well, that button doesn't show up inside of your <form> tags based on the code you're showing.

Also, you don't need to open and close php with every line. Just do <?php at the beginning and ?>  at the end. And like I said, you're refreshing the page each time, also.

Comment: it is inside my form tags, I used the <?php ?> so I could be able to create tags and use my php variables

Comment: Right, but you don't need to open and close them for each line. You can literally get rid of all of the php tags after the first one and before the last one.

Comment: yeah but thats beside my point, still dont get the right value from my input

Comment: Well, your code would be much easier to read if it was a little cleaner. And cleaner code is easier to troubleshoot. 
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e19808f0d203a994fe170e602d8fcedc9b8ecf65

Comment: I suspect your problem lies with the fact that you're refreshing after every page and not getting your post variables as you expect them. Like I said, you have some fundamental structural problems here.

Ideally, if you have multiple forms on a page, you should use AJAX to submit each form. It's a little extra work but not that much.

Comment: @Difster -  IMHO, it would be even more readable if you closed the PHP tag before outputting the HTML and then open it again after the HTML is outputted. When adding/echoing PHP variables, just use `<?= $someVar ?>`. That way, IDE's will also highlight the HTML as HTML.

Comment: There's also a typo: `class=image'` (missing opening `'`). A semi-decent IDE would have caught that it the HTML wasn't outputted as PHP strings using echo.

Answer (score 2):

You are passing the value in the tag as value = '1' so this takes precedence over the actual input. Remove it and pass

```
   echo "<input type='number' name='qte' min = '1'/>";
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: I removed it and it still gives me 1

Comment: What does the 'btnAjout' refer to in this context?

Comment: Setting an initial value on an input is totally fine. If it's changed, the changed value will be used. Otherwise, how would you be able to prefill forms?

Comment: I meant to write 'btnAdd' name of the button

Comment: @MagnusEriksson what do you mean by being able to prefill form?

Comment: @Cory - Prefilling a form is when you're setting the default values so the user don't need to fill out known values again.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the **value** attribute from this line:

```
echo "<input type='number' name='qte' value='1' min = '1'/>";
```

into

```
echo "<input type='number' name='qte' min = '1'/>";
```

I hope this would be helpful.

Comment: Check timing to other comment and my comment. Why my answer is not accepted because of the first?

Comment: ...interesting. Until I refreshed the page, it showed the other answer as having been entered first.

Comment: I think the earlier answered to sort down below

Comment: I don't think any of the answers address the OP's actual issue. How would omitting to set an initial value on the input solve the problem at hand?